# Use Join or Sub Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `Student`, `Address` and `StudentAddress`.

`Student` stores all the students, address stores all the address details while `StudentAddress` resolves many to many relationship between `Student` and `Address`. This table stores details of student who have lived in more than one addresses.

I am trying to list the Names and address details of a student who has changed his address more than 5 times.

```
SELECT a.StudentID, CONCAT(b.FirstName + " " + b.LastName), c.MajorMunicipality,
       COUNT(a.AddressID) AS count 
FROM StudentAddress a 
INNER JOIN Member b 
        ON a.StudentID = b.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Address c 
        ON a.AddressID = b.AddressID
GROUP BY a.StudentID, a.AddressID 
HAVING count > 5;
```

This query has issues with joining. Please help!!

Comment: If you can always use joins - they are faster than subqueries. Read more about the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query?rq=1

Comment: how do you know that the address is changed ? is there any flag to determine this ?

Comment: Note that, technically, you should be grouping by both memberid and addressid (or, more likely, not selecting addressid at all) - otherwise, which address is being returned?

Comment: @MrCoder: What Strawberry is saying is: So far you select a random AddressID, because it's neither in the GROUP BY clause nor being aggregated by an aggregate function such as MIN, MAX and the like. EDIT: Ah, now Strawberry has edited his/her comment, so my elaboration doesn't add much anymore :-)

Comment: How do you determine the current address?

Comment: I dont need to determine current one. Will count the number of addresses in MemberAddress which will mean customer has had lived at that many addresses. Please check my query and let me know where am going wrong now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer `join` since it gives your more possibilities to use the result for your second query.

To help you narrowing down the actual result set, try something like this:

```
select a.MemberID
,      a.AddressID
,      COUNT(a.AddressID) as countAddress
from   MemberAddress a
group
by     a.MemberID
,      a.AddressID
having countAddress > 3
;
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
select a.memberid
,      concat(b.firstname + " " + b.lastname)
,      c.majormunicipality
,      count(a.addressid) as countAddresses
from   memberaddress a 
join   member b 
on     a.memberid = b.memberid 
join   address c 
on     a.addressid = b.addressid
group
by     a.memberid
,      concat(b.firstname + " " + b.lastname)
,      c.majormunicipality
having count > 5
;
```

Comment: I have added the new query in my post. Could you please check it..?

Comment: I mean the query, I have mentioned in my post. It is the updated one now.

Comment: Thing is, I am trying to fetch the members who have changed their addresses more than 5 times. MemberAddress gives me that result. However, I now need to fetch Member and address details which are stored in member and address tables.

Comment: Can you rename your count parameter? I think that might be the issue

Comment: Count parameter refers to AddressID of MemberAddress. What could be the issue with it?

Comment: Count is a preserved keyword. You shouldn't use it as column name.

Comment: Also, you need `c.MajorMunicipality` in your `group by`.

Comment: @MrCoder: any luck in fixing this?

Comment: @MrCoder: Try the last sql in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To filter them:

```
select a.MemberID,a.AddressID,COUNT(a.AddressID) as count 
from MemberAddress a group by a.MemberID HAVING COUNT(a.AddressID) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use HAVING Clause

```
      SELECT a.MemberID,
      a.AddressID,
      COUNT(a.AddressID) AS COUNT
      FROM MemberAddress a
      GROUP BY a.MemberID;
      HAVING COUNT >=3
```